# Kentico 13 API SearchHelper.Search returns different object type in .net core than it does in .net mvc

Tags: asp.net-core, search, kentico

Not sure if anyone has come across this, but currently porting a K13 MVC project over to K13 .Net core (5.0) - both using the same CMS just different Kentico libraries packages but of same hotfix version.

standard Search API functionality being used in both with exact same parameters for a search query but finding that .net core instance will return a TreeNode in its searchResults.Items Data object where the MVC would return its stronglyTyped object

**Function**

```
        protected ItemsAndCount<News> GetItemsAndCount(string nodeAliasPath, int pageSize = 12, string searchText = "", int currentPage = 0, int category = 0, int year = 0)
    {
        var culture = LocalizationContext.CurrentCulture.CultureCode;
        var defaultCulture = CultureHelper.GetDefaultCultureCode(SiteContext.CurrentSiteName);
        var combineWithDefaultCulture = SiteInfoProvider.CombineWithDefaultCulture(SiteContext.CurrentSiteName);
        var documentTypes = News.CLASS_NAME;
        var docCondition = new DocumentSearchCondition(documentTypes, culture, defaultCulture, combineWithDefaultCulture);
        var condition = new SearchCondition(GetExtraConditions(category, year), SearchModeEnum.ExactPhrase, SearchOptionsEnum.NoneSearch, docCondition, false);
        var query = ValidationHelper.GetString(searchText, string.Empty);
        var path = nodeAliasPath + "/";

        var parameters = new SearchParameters
        {
            Path = path,
            SearchFor = SearchSyntaxHelper.CombineSearchCondition(query, condition),
            SearchSort = OrderBy,
            CurrentCulture = LocalizationContext.CurrentCulture.CultureCode,
            DefaultCulture = CultureHelper.GetDefaultCultureCode(SiteContext.CurrentSiteName),
            CombineWithDefaultCulture = SiteInfoProvider.CombineWithDefaultCulture(SiteContext.CurrentSiteName),
            User = MembershipContext.AuthenticatedUser,
            SearchIndexes = SearchIndexHelper.SEARCHINDEX_NEWS,
            DisplayResults = pageSize,
            StartingPosition = currentPage == 0 ? 0 : (currentPage - 1) * pageSize,
            NumberOfProcessedResults = 10000
        };

        var searchResult = SearchHelper.Search(parameters);
        //TotalNoOfRecords = searchResult.TotalNumberOfResults;

        return new ItemsAndCount<News>
        {
            Items = GetItems(searchResult.Items).ToList(),
            Count = searchResult.TotalNumberOfResults
        };
    }
```

[image: Debug Results on each side by side]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this turned out to be an issue due to having all generated code files in a separate library

https://docs.xperience.io/custom-development/adding-custom-assemblies#Addingcustomassemblies-Enablingclassdiscovery

what was throwing me is that all the rest of the site was actually running as expected without this, only searchitems & customtableitems where not returning as strongly typed.

Answer (score 0):

So according to the [API docs](https://devnet.kentico.com/docs/13_0/api/html/M_CMS_Search_SearchHelper_Search.htm) for `SearchHelper`, this does look like intended behavior. But you don't actually ***have*** to use SearchHelper. You could call the Azure Search client directly and work with the **SearchDocument** object it returns. An example of this is in the [LearningKit for 13](https://github.com/KenticoInternal/LearningKit-Mvc/blob/fc4f384cd77d92ff7773266d8997aca7b378431d/LearningKit/Controllers/Search/AzureSearchController.cs).